# Sum of the values of the previous dates in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to take the sum of the values of previous dates except current date by Product. Given below is the dataset. In the output table, I have mentioned how my summation of values of previous dates should look like.

For Eg: For the date 7/27/2014 I want the summation of the previous dates except current date by product level. Similarly when you are taking the summation for 7/20/2014 ignore the values for 7/20/2014 and also 7/27/2014 and take rest of the previous dates.
Also there is a exception here. When you see duplicates for example 7/20/2014 and 6/8/2014 consider just one value.

```
DATE    DEALID      PRODUCT      VALUE
7/27/2014   6575    CLIENT      4
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/13/2014   6601    CLIENT      4
7/6/2014    10871   SERVICES    5
6/29/2014   16661   SERVICES    2
6/22/2014   66757   SERVICES    1
6/15/2014   77757   SERVICES    5
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
5/25/2014   5756    SERVICES    4
```

output table

```
DATE    DEALID  PRODUCT       VALUE SUMM
7/27/2014   6575    CLIENT      4   10
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6   4
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6   4
7/13/2014   6601    CLIENT      4   0
7/6/2014    10871   SERVICES    5   20
6/29/2014   16661   SERVICES    2   18
6/22/2014   66757   SERVICES    1   17
6/15/2014   77757   SERVICES    5   12
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8   4
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8   4
5/25/2014   5756    SERVICES    4   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain old SAS data steps are usualy more practical and often run faster for very specific requirements.

**Let us start like NEO_mental to create the data**

```
data test;
                infile datalines;
                format date mmddyy10.; /** Make SAS print dates as a date instead of numbers **/
                input date : mmddyy10. 
                                  Dealid : $ 8.
                                  PRODUCT : $10.
                                  Value : 8.
                                  ;
datalines;
7/27/2014   6575    CLIENT      4
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/13/2014   6601    CLIENT      4
7/6/2014    10871   SERVICES    5
6/29/2014   16661   SERVICES    2
6/22/2014   66757   SERVICES    1
6/15/2014   77757   SERVICES    5
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
5/25/2014   5756    SERVICES    4
;
run;
```

**To calculate a running total, I sort in ascending date order.
I do not remove duplicates, as I handle them in my data step.**

```
proc sort data=test out=ascendingTest;
                by Product Date;
run;
```

**Here comes the good old data step, in which I do all the calculations**

```
/** Create a dataset including the running total **/
Data summTest;

                /** Read in the data **/
                set ascendingTest;

                /** Enable things like first.Product and last.Date **/
                by Product Date;

                /** Create the running total **/
                /** variables are initialised for each observation (=row) unless you retain them **/
                retain Summ;
                if first.Product then Summ = 0; /** Start over for each product **/

                /** Write out the result BEFORE increasing the total **/
                output;

                /** Increase the running total for the later dates **/
                if last.Date then Summ = Summ + Value;
run;
```

**As we did not remove duplicates, I do not need to merge, so all I have to do is to sort on descending date agian.**
Note: if performance is an issue, write 'Data summTest / view=summTest. This way the data step will not read any data and the calculations will only be done when the sort step consumes the results.
;

```
proc sort data=summTest out=final;
                by Product descending Date ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if thats the best way to do it.

Run a proc sql to get the distinct dates and store them into variables like date1 - dateN.
Another proc sql to count the distinct dates and store the quantity into a variable called count or something.

Then create an empty table with the same columns as the original plus the sum column, do a loop through the dates, summing all the values where the table date is < than the date in the loop, to finally insert the results into the empty table.

You could use tables instead of date1-dateN variables too if there are too many dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reproducible code

**Using Datalines to read the dataset**

```
data test;
infile datalines;
input date : mmddyy10.
      Dealid : $ 8.
      PRODUCT : $10.
      Value : 8.
      ;
datalines;
7/27/2014   6575    CLIENT      4
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/20/2014   16701   CLIENT      6
7/13/2014   6601    CLIENT      4
7/6/2014    10871   SERVICES    5
6/29/2014   16661   SERVICES    2
6/22/2014   66757   SERVICES    1
6/15/2014   77757   SERVICES    5
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
6/8/2014    5675    SERVICES    8
5/25/2014   5756    SERVICES    4
;
run;
```

**Removing the duplicate dates from each product**

```
proc sort data=test nodupkey out=test1;
by PRODUCT date;
run;
```

**Summarizing the dataset on Value based on Product (notice nway)**

```
proc summary data=test1 nway;
class PRODUCT;
var Value;
output out=test2(drop = _type_ _freq_)
sum(Value)=Value_summ;
run;
```

**Sorting and merging back to the original dataset and doing further calculations**

```
proc sort data=test;
by PRODUCT;
run;

proc sort data=test2;
by PRODUCT;
run;
```

- Using lag to check if there are duplicates in the date
- Checking lag in date, if they are same then SUMM would retain the previous value but to avoid circumstances where dates are same in two different products residing in consecutive records, there is 'OR' condition which would check if the PRODUCT in previous record is different or not, if it would be then it would go for substraction, hope that makes sense

---

```
data FINAL(drop=date_lag product_lag);
retain SUMM;
format date mmddyy10.;
merge test(in=a) test2(in=b);
by PRODUCT;
date_lag=lag(date);
product_lag=lag(product);
if date ne date_lag or product ne product_lag then SUMM=SUMM-value;
run;
```